# Hiding divs until it's selected by its data filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working from a Bootstrap template and want to change the "portfolio section". At the moment all the images loaded in HTML shows by default and then, once a heading is selected, the images are cleared and only the ones connected to that heading (data filter) is shown.

I only want to change the default behavior.  By default, none of the images must show. And then, once a heading is selected the images load like explained above.

Here's the Javascript:

```
 // portfolio filter
$(window).load(function() {
    'use strict',
    $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
    if ($portfolio_selectors != 'undefined') {
        $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
        $portfolio.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.col-sm-3',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });

        $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function() {
            $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $portfolio.isotope({
                filter: selector
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <h2 class="title-one">Portfolio</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">
            <li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".html">Html</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".wordpress">Wordpress</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".joomla">Joomla</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".megento">Megento</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--/#portfolio-filter-->
        <div class="portfolio-items">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/our-team/bella.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item jooma">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/our-team/constance.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item4.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/our-team/francell.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item megento">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/6.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/7.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item joomla">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/8.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/9.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/10.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item joomla">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/11.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item3.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item megento">
                <div class="view efffect">
                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/12.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask text-center">
                        <h3>Novel</h3>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                        <a href="images/portfolio/big-item4.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
<!--/#portfolio-->
```

Comment: Your best bet will be to inspect the HTML to find out how Bootstrap is hiding elements, then mimic that approach in your CSS (e.g. if Bootstrap is adding display: none to `portfolio-item`, then you'll want your initial CSS to apply display: none to all of those items). This way you will avoid conflict between what you do to hide initially and what Bootstrap needs to do to later show/hide.

Comment: I found inconsistency on the click function. Firstly you initialized '$portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });' where not declared '$portfolio' in this function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear all images by default when page loads using [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) you are suppose to set a **dummy filter on isotope initiation**. Check below snippet for  example(check on full screen view to get a better understanding). Here I added `filter: '.dummy'` to hide all images by default.

```js
// portfolio filter
$(window).load(function() {
  'use strict',
  $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
  if ($portfolio_selectors != 'undefined') {
    $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
    $portfolio.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.col-sm-3',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows',
      filter: '.dummy'
    });

    $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function() {
      $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $portfolio.isotope({
        filter: selector
      });
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.4/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <h2 class="title-one">Portfolio</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">
      <li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
      <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".html">Html</a></li>
      <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".wordpress">Wordpress</a></li>
      <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".joomla">Joomla</a></li>
      <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".megento">Megento</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--/#portfolio-filter-->
    <div class="portfolio-items">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/our-team/bella.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item jooma">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/our-team/constance.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item4.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/our-team/francell.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item megento">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/5.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/6.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/7.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item joomla">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/8.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/9.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/10.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item joomla">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/11.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item3.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item megento">
        <div class="view efffect">
          <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="images/portfolio/12.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="mask text-center">
            <h3>Novel</h3>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
            <a href="images/portfolio/big-item4.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<!--/#portfolio-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed somethings in your code:

- `isotope` not recognized so I removed it.
- I replaced the way you were searching for the items to hide\show with:

  `$('.portfolio-item').not(selector).hide();
  $('.portfolio-item'+selector).show();`

```js
// portfolio filter
$portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
if($portfolio_selectors!='undefined'){
$portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
/*
$portfolio.isotope({
itemSelector : '.col-sm-3',
layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});
*/

$portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
$portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

$('.portfolio-item').not(selector).hide();
$('.portfolio-item'+selector).show();

return false;
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="portfolio">
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<h2 class="title-one">Portfolio</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit.</p>
</div>
</div>
<ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">
<li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
<li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".html">Html</a></li>
<li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".wordpress">Wordpress</a></li>
<li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".joomla">Joomla</a></li>
<li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".megento">Megento</a></li>
</ul><!--/#portfolio-filter-->
<div class="portfolio-items">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/our-team/bella.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item jooma">
<div class="view efffect" >
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/our-team/constance.jpg" alt="">
</div>
  <div class="mask text-center html">
    <h3>.html</h3>
    <h4> .html.html.html.html</h4>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    <a href="images/portfolio/big-item4.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
  <div class="view efffect">
  <div class="portfolio-image">
  <img src="images/our-team/francell.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item megento">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/5.jpg" alt="">
</div> <div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/6.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/7.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item joomla">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/8.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item html">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/9.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item wordpress">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/10.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item joomla">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/11.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item3.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item megento">
<div class="view efffect">
<div class="portfolio-image">
<img src="images/portfolio/12.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="mask text-center">
<h3>Novel</h3>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h4>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<a href="images/portfolio/big-item4.jpg" data-gallery="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</section> <!--/#portfolio-->
```